# Is there a way to include images that are of "mp4" and "webM" format from an api call?

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning everyone!

I'm currently accessing an API to display a random image of dogs. Now, it's working; however, the function only shows the images that are ".gif" or ".img" format. If the images are of ".mp4" or "WebM" format, then the feature won't display the image.

I've tried to create an if statement that will allow me to access the ".mp4" and ".WebM" images, should they appear. In theory, it works. I've used .split to access the last part of the file, whether it's ".mp4" or "WebM," however, no changes are being made in comparison to what I initially need for it to do, (which is to display the image, regardless of its file type). The code that I'm posting is as far as I've managed to get in regards to progress. I'm stuck on how to proceed forward with it.

```
const userAction = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://random.dog/woof.json');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    return myJson.url
};


function button() {
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = async function () {
        const src = await userAction();
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = src;
        img.width = 500;
        img.height = 500;
        img.alt = "doggo";
        img.id = 'doggo_image';
        let pieces = src.split(".");

        // Need to figure this part out
        if (pieces[pieces.length-1] === "mp4" || pieces[pieces.length-1] === "webM") {
            let video = document.createElement("video");
            document.body.append(video);
        } else {

        }

        const current_image = document.getElementById(img.id);
        if (current_image) {
            document.body.replaceChild(img, current_image);
        } else {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
    };
}
```

I'm expecting for the code to print the image if it's mp4, webM, or img. Right now, it's currently only printing img files from the api.

Comment: You create the `<video>` element but you do nothing to associate it with the URL.

Comment: How would Id o that? Could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not associating the video element with the source of the video.

So before appending the element to the DOM, you need to add the src:

```
        let video = document.createElement("video");
        video.src = src;
        document.body.append(video);
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much. It's now displaying mp4 pictures and Webm. Any recommendations on improving this code to display the image? This way, it replaces the file regardless of if it's "img", "webM", or "mp4." 

       `const current_image = document.getElementById(img.id);
        if (current_image) {
        document.body.replaceChild(img, current_image);
        } else {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
    };
}`